# NSNotificationCenter and Tap Method calling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So i have an ios app which has Two Tabs. First tab has a UIGestureRecognizer which calls a countdown Method once its TAPPED.

Second tab has a UIPickerView with Three selections.

This is what i have in my secondTab's ViewController in code:

```
   FirstViewController *firstvs = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
   NSInteger selectedRow = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0];


if (selectedRow == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid Row"); // This block will not do nothing
}
else if (selectedRow == 1) {

    // Call a method in firstViewController
    [firstvs smallSelection];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                                         postNotificationName:@"smallSelection2"
                                                                               object:self];

}
else if (selectedRow == 2) {

    [firstvs mediumSelection];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                                         postNotificationName:@"mediumSelection3"
                                                                                object:self];
}
else if (selectedRow == 3){

    [firstvs largeSelection];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                                         postNotificationName:@"largeSelection"
                                                                               object:self];
}
```

What this basically does is if the USER selects lets say, Row 2, Within the same secondTab it dispays in a UILabel what the user has selected.

Now then, that selection is broadcasted in a NSNotificationCenter as shown in the code under each if and else block.

*I have 3 NSnotificationCenter for each if Statement which i clearly dont know if its safe to do this or not aside from my problem.

So when the user selects Option 2 which would be row 2, In the First tab's ViewController, it calls a method called mediumSelection.

In FirstViewController.m :

```
-(void)mediumSelection {
  // Other functions
 }
```

But as you may notice i rather use an NSNotificationCenter to keep the firstViewController Listening to the secondViewController's instead of just executing this method as i been recommended to use the NSNotificationCenter.
Notice this NSNotification Broadcaster in the selection 2 on secondViewController:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   postNotificationName:@"mediumSelection3"object:self];
```

This Broadcaster then sends a message to the listener as i show the code from the firstViewController Now:

```
     - (id) init
      {
         self = [super init];
          if (!self) return nil;
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(smallSelection2:)
                                             name:@"smallSelection2"
                                           object:nil];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(mediumSelection3:)
                                             name:@"mediumSelection3"
                                           object:nil];

                              return self;
                            }

               - (void) smallSelection2:(NSNotification *) notification
                   {
                    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"smallSelection2"])
                   NSLog (@"SmallSelection is successfully received!");



                                                        }
                  - (void) mediumSelection3:(NSNotification *) notification
                    {
                      if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"mediumSelection3"])
                         NSLog (@"mediumSelection is successfully received!");


                         }
```

So this works, It logs it into the Console as the the UIPicker is being used to scroll it recieves the selection. Now for the BIG problem and the main reason this NSNotification is meant for.

Before this Reciever code, Above i have the UIGestureRecognizer and the countdown method called from the Tap as Follows:

```
      -(void) viewDidLoad {
       UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScreen = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:       self action:@selector(tapScreen:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: tapScreen];
       }

  - (void) tapScreen:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr
 { 
    NSLog(@"Screen has been tapped");

/*
  CODE RELATED TO LABELS, NOTHING IMPORTANT
*/

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 target: self selector:      @selector(countdown) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];

 }

-(void) countdown { 

/*
MORE CODE BEING EXECUTED ON THE VIEW
*/

NSLog(@"Program success: counting... %i", mainInteger);

self.hoursLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i hours", mainInteger];

self.percentGauge.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", subInteger];



       // FIGURE 1:
      [self smallSelection];

   }
```

Now the Problem is i want the countdown to begin according to the selection Made from the NSNotificationCenter. So if the user selected Row 2 from the Picker, the countdown goes from that selection according to the methods "Small, Medium, Large".

as you can see, in the end of the countdown method where it says "FIGURE 1:" I am manually calling the smallSelection Method which i would like to embed an If statement to check the 3 possible choices according to the UIPicker selection, i am using NSNotificationCenter because i was testing if this was would work aside from the instance i set on secondViewController
called: [firstvs smallSelection].

So is there anyway to add an if statement to check the 3 possible choices and to execute that method on a tap ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a global object where all values are written down and change these values from different the viewcontrollers.

So you can get the values from all viewcontrollers using this global object:

[image]

Comment: How does this solve the program's main intention of calling the methods when the Screen is tapped? This seems more to work with like delegation and or singleton ?